# Modified Arrhenius equation in the presence of a heterogeneous catalyst

Tags: kinetics, catalysis, surface-chemistry

Suppose we are doing heterogeneous catalysis, for example, between nitrogen and hydrogen to create ammonia in the presence of a solid catalyst, like rhuthenium. It's obvious that the gas molecules don't "collide" directly and, therefore, the [Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation) does not completely apply. Does a modified version of the equation exist that takes this into account?

My guess would be that since catalysts generally decrease the activation energy of a reaction, the activation energy value would possibly have a fractional component to it. Furthermore, because the reaction is occurring on a surface, the decreased direct collisions may affect the rate. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Being catalyzed is not the major modification factor. The major factor is becoming a reaction on solid surface, instead in free volume.

Comment: I would start with the 2D model of the multistep reaction mechanism, each step having its own activation energy. ( so does not catalyzed reaction if free space )